# Change "NA" strings to -99.99

Tags: r, replace, na

I am trying to replace NA strings to -99.99 in my list of data frames in order to run my data in RCLIMDEX.

This is the structure of one of my data frames, they all have the same number of columns and row header.

```
     year month day Pr Tx2m Tn2m
1 1987    12  31 NA   NA   NA
2 1988     1   1  0   NA   NA
3 1988     1   2  0   NA   NA
4 1988     1   3  0   NA   NA
5 1988     1   4  0   NA   NA
6 1988     1   5  0   NA   NA
```

I have tried using the following:

```
estaciones <- lapply(estaciones, function(x) {x[x==is.na] <- "-99.99"; return(x)})
```

and

```
 estaciones <- lapply(estaciones, function(x){
  x[, 'is.na'] <- -99.99
  return(x)
})
```

neither of those lines return my data frames with -99.99 values replaced, they are still NA.

what can I use to replace NA strings to -99.99? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is.na` is a function and it should be applied on those variables.

```
estaciones[] <- lapply(estaciones, function(x) {
       x[is.na(x)] <- "-99.99"
        return(x)})
```

---

Or simply apply `is.na` on the entire data to create a logical matrix, use that to subset the original data and assign those values to `-99.99`

```
estaciones[is.na(estacioes)] <- "-99.99"
```